# Change "Shared drive settings" of Google Shared Drive

Tags: go, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I want to change "Shared drive settings" of Google Shared Drive by Google Drive API with Golang.

I set false to "DomainUsersOnly" and ”DriveMembersOnly" of "Shared drive settings" when I created shared drive.
But it was not working.

I referred to the link below.

link：https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api@v0.52.0/drive/v3#DriveRestrictions

```
// restrict := &drive.DriveRestrictions{
//  AdminManagedRestrictions: false,
//  DomainUsersOnly:          false,
//  DriveMembersOnly:         false,
// }

// exFolder := &drive.Drive{
//  Name:         "試験_ZZ_TEST",
//  Restrictions: restrict,
// }

// res, err := drive.NewDrivesService(srv).Create(reqId, exFolder).Do()
// if err != nil {
//  log.Fatalf("Can not create shared drive: %v /n", err)
// }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify these boolean fields in `ForceSendFields`.

```golang
restrict := &drive.DriveRestrictions{
  AdminManagedRestrictions: false,
  DomainUsersOnly:          false,
  DriveMembersOnly:         false,
  ForceSendFields: []string{"AdminManagedRestrictions", "DomainUsersOnly", "DriveMembersOnly"},
  NullFields: []string{"AdminManagedRestrictions", "DomainUsersOnly", "DriveMembersOnly"},
}
```

document of `ForceSendFields`

```
    // ForceSendFields is a list of field names (e.g.
    // "AdminManagedRestrictions") to unconditionally include in API
    // requests. By default, fields with empty or default values are omitted
    // from API requests. However, any non-pointer, non-interface field
    // appearing in ForceSendFields will be sent to the server regardless of
    // whether the field is empty or not. This may be used to include empty
    // fields in Patch requests.
    ForceSendFields []string `json:"-"`
```

Comment: Thank you for your support.
but it was not working.

Comment: t := time.Now()
reqId := "userid" + t.Format(layout)
fmt.Printf("reqid : %v \n", reqId)

restrict := &drive.DriveRestrictions{
  AdminManagedRestrictions: false,
  DomainUsersOnly:          false,
  DriveMembersOnly:         false,
  ForceSendFields:          []string{"AdminManagedRestrictions", "DomainUsersOnly", "DriveMembersOnly"},
 }

exFolder := &drive.Drive{
  Name:         "testShrareDrive",
  Restrictions: restrict,
 }

res, err := drive.NewDrivesService(srv).Create(reqId, exFolder).Do()
if err != nil {
 log.Fatalf("Can not create shared drive: %v /n", err)
}'

Comment: Could you please let me know any mistake

Comment: Please more support for me

Comment: updated my answer, you could also try another field `NullFields`

Answer (score 0):

it was not working when created,
but it was working then update.
parameter of true was checkbox off.

```
restrict := &drive.DriveRestrictions{
    DomainUsersOnly:  true,
    DriveMembersOnly: true,
}

newmetadate.Restrictions = restrict

res, err := srv.Drives.Update(did, newmetadate).UseDomainAdminAccess(true).Do()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("error update shared drive: %v /n", err)
}
```